# Perform transformation on certain keys in a collection in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, collections, key, lodash

Let's say I have a collection like this:

```
var myCollection = [
    {
        name: 'Foo',
        age: 35
    },{
        name: 'Bar',
        age: 32
    },{
        secondRow: [
            {
                name: 'FooFoo',
                age: 21
            },          {
                name: 'BarBar',
                age: 25
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

I want to iterate over this collection (with arbitrary depth) and add 10 years to every value with the key `age`.

How would I do this?

I'm happy to use lodash if necessary, but vanilla JS is good too.

Comment: Can you show is what you've tried thus far?

Comment: I don't really know how to being I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach for getting all `age` properties for update.

```js
function add10(object) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (key) {
        if (object[key] && typeof object[key] === 'object') {
            return add10(object[key]);
        }
        if (key === 'age') {
            object.age += 10;
        }
    });
}

var myCollection = [{ name: 'Foo', age: 35 }, { name: 'Bar', age: 32 }, { secondRow: [{ name: 'FooFoo', age: 21 }, { name: 'BarBar', age: 25 }] }];

add10(myCollection);
console.log(myCollection);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think this is it! Thank you!

Comment: @NinaScholz why didn't you return the object inside the function?

Comment: @Arrow, no need to return something. the object has a reference to the object and the return inside of `forEach`  just exits the callback (with `undefined`).

Comment: @NinaScholz Ohhoo,   so does that mean it is not good to return it when it is not necessary. Am I unpacking the function or am I calling it unnecessarily by returning it

Comment: @Arrow, the return is depending of the purpose. if you need a function which is chainable, like `Object.assign`, where you get the target parameter/object back, then return the object. but not always is this behaviour needed.